# Search for a file name in Android Studio's Device File Explorer

Tags: android-studio

Is there a search feature in "Device File Explorer" from Android Studio, similar to search in "Windows File Explorer" to search a device attached to Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

There is no search function in the Device File Explorer.

But you can open the Terminal, type `adb shell` (which will open an interactive shell for your device) and then you can use the unix `find` command to search for files.

For example: `find /sdcard/Download -name *.apk` would list all .apk files inside /sdcard/Download

Comment: This helps.  when in terminal I get

Comment: This helps.  find /sdcard/Download -name *.apk works in shell. But find /.  -name '*.apk   gives me a long list of "  find: './proc/263/task/263/net/stat/rt_cache': Permission denied" and alike.

Comment: Yes, you won't be able able too look at every folder in the device, just as in the Device File Explorer. If the device is rooted and you need to look at those fodlers you can do sudo first and then execute the search.

Comment: 127|beyond1q:/ $ find /sdcard/Download -name video48a.apk
/sdcard/Download/video48a.apk
beyond1q:/ $ sudo
/system/bin/sh: sudo: inaccessible or not found
127|beyond1q:/ $ su
/system/bin/sh: su: inaccessible or not found
127|beyond1q:/ $    So, for me find does work, but  neither sudo nor su work.

Answer (score 2):

There actually is a search function. All you need to do is start typing when you have the device file explorer open and have a file selected. As far as I know it can only search the contents of open folders.

Answer (score -1):

There is a search function in Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: By everywhere they mean within the project.  I am looking for a search on the phone, ATTACHED over USB or WiFi, where I run my project.